# go get pseudo-version changes when I do go mod tidy

Tags: go, dependencies

I am trying to go get a pseudo-version.

> Example: `go get abc.dummy.com/something@v0.0.0-20220504124741-2726f7d8a8a4`

But this is giving me error:

> go get: abc.dummy.com/something@v0.0.0-20220504124741-2726f7d8a8a4 requires abc.dummy.com/something@v0.2.4, not abc.dummy.com/something@v0.0.0-20220504124741-2726f7d8a8a4

I don't know why this error is happening. I tried to delete the mod file, but did `go mod init...` again. Again did `go get .....` It fetched successfully. But as soon as I Did `go mod tidy` it reverted back to previous dependencies.

Stucked here... Help??

Comment: I don't know why it is pointing or requiring at v0.2.4. It is nowhere related to that. My repo has the latest release tag of v0.8.0